# Create hundreds of users with just ID in phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, id, table

I'm trying to do the same as [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/import-10-000-users-into-wordpress-with-a-specific-id-for-each-user). But I have a problem with the

> insert records into your wp_users table containing all the ID's of the
>   members you want to import

Right now, I have 3 members with respectively ID 1, 11 and 12. But I need to insert 500 users, with ID from 2 to 502. How do I create these ID line in my database without creating one by one ? Right now, I know how to add one at a time, but it starts at id 510 (because I've deleted older users). I want to start at ID 2...

Thanks a lot !

Cédric

Comment: The post you found appears to answer your question. Why do the answers there not work for you?

Comment: He doesn't explain how to create the X fake users to have the ID's created :(

Comment: Well, where are your new users coming from? Another database? A CSV file? What? You can't restart at 2 without considerable difficulty, by the way, because you already have users with IDs higher than that, and what is the point? It is just an identifier. It can be anything.

Comment: The projects was done in Ruby on rails. Now we are making it with Wordpress. The database is coming from the Ruby project. So I have users related to some posts. I need to keep the good ID for a users to keep the link betweens post and users. So my users are in a CSV file. Why is that a problem to start back to ID 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the initial ID user by mysql

```
ALTER TABLE wp_users AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

although the number has to start at the next available id with no existing id higher, as in

```
select max(id) from wp_users;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql